# System.NullReferenceException at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase.Dispose(Boolean) at PrjSpecAddIn.Oberon.Dispose(Boolean)

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, office-addins, ribbonx

I created two similar VSTO addins and the first one compiles and works on all machines, but the second one (with similar functionality, but having Windows Forms components does not work, does not start correctly on any machine except mine). Second addin have an error "System.NullReferenceException at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase.Dispose(Boolean) at PrjSpecAddIn.Oberon.Dispose(Boolean) at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize()".
I searched for possible solutions here and in the rest of the Internet, but none of the methods helped me. I even tried to move the code from the second add-in to the first, but I still get the error.
I don't use third party libraries. Only Microsofts namespaces.

Comment: Do you get any problems with a newly created VSTO add-in project? What ribbon customizations did you make in the add-in?

Comment: I have problems, when i created ribbon, added button and write some code (that only open Excel file). I dont make any customization except rename buttons or tab.

Comment: Well, you need to go through this process step-by-step to find the cause. It seems the problem is in your ribbon-related code.